# Detect end of line in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, eol

This is the code which read a matrix 10x10 from a file "F1.txt"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    FILE * fr;
    fr = fopen("F1.txt","r");

    int i, j;
    int matrix[10][10] = {0.0}; 

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fr, "%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            printf("%d\n", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

"F1.txt" looks like this:

```
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 4 34 56 43 32 124 52 212 3
32 343 34 544 43 32 7 52 456 98
```

It works without problems but the output is:

```
12
343
34
544
43
32
124
52
212
3
12
343
34
544
43
32
124
52
212
..........
etc....
```

I have to detect the end of line to make my input the same like in F1.txt

```
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 343 34 544 43 32 124 52 212 3
12 4 34 56 43 32 124 52 212 3
32 343 34 544 43 32 7 52 456 98
```

.

Comment: `int matrix[10][10] = {0.0};` You mean `int matrix[10][10] = {0};`, right?

Comment: Yeah. it's actually running without = {0.0};

Comment: this question doesn't show any research and effort. Just replacing `\n` character to ` ` will done the maximum job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the loops the following way

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fr, "%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        printf("%3d ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the data correctly, but you are not printing it right. Your program inserts `'\n'` after each character, that's why you see so many lines.

Change your program like this to see the output that you expect:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fr, "%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]); // <<== Replace \n with a single space
    }
    printf("\n"); // <<== Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you just want your input formatted, you can write your end of line in the outer loop on `i`.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fr, "%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your knowledge, EOL is usually a `LF` character or combination of `CR-LF` characters. In C they are represented by `\n` or `\r\n` respectively.

A possible solution is that you can use `fgets` to read a complete line at once (`fgets` will read one line only by itself). Then read out the integers from that string using `sscanf` or `strtok`.

I suggest you to use `sscanf` if you know number of integers in every line.

Otherwise, if a line can contain any amount of numbers then you can use `strtok` with `" "` (space) as the delimitter.

You can read more about these functions here: [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) , [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(fr, "%d",&matrix[i][j]);
printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
if(j < 10-1)
    printf(" ");
else
    printf("\n");
```